# ios swift parse: how to collect pointer data

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have this query:

```
        var query = PFQuery(className: "CardSet")
        query.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser())
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

            if (error == nil) {

                // found

            }else{
                println(error.userInfo)
            }
        }
```

The result looks like this:

```
<CardSet: 0x7c892120, objectId: 2yty7cpnyF, localId: (null)> {
    ACL = "<PFACL: 0x7be65450>";
    lesson = "<Lesson: 0x7beaabd0, objectId: JV7trFTx5Z>";
    name = "I am your CardSet";
    public = 1;
    user = "<PFUser: 0x7be834a0, objectId: baz8ObNsmM>";
}
```

Class "CardSet" has a pointer "lesson" to class "Lesson".
What can I do to have Lesson.name available in the query result? Or do I need to query a second time? That would be bad because of the amount of requests to parse...? Is there any better way getting all pointed data in just one query?

Comment: did you try create a Lesson object = cardSet.lesson?

Comment: wehre do I need to do that?

Comment: were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 10):

You can tell Parse to fetch a related object using the `includeKey` method:

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "CardSet")
query.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser())
query.includeKey("lesson")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) in
    for cardset in objects {
        var lesson = cardset["lesson"] as PFObject
        var name = lesson["name"] as String
        println("retrieved related lesson: \(post) with name: \(name)")
    }
}
```

Mentioned in the [Relational Queries](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries-relational/iOS) section of the documentation.

Comment: But even then, I can not access anyhow lesson.name? I get the lesson object back in the query, as you can see, but how can I make the details of lesson visible with the above query? Adding the includeKey does not the trick?

Comment: I am also dealing with pointers, not relations, maybe thats why includeKey does not get the data?

Comment: I'm pretty certain that includeKey should work with pointers. Are you using custom PFObject subclasses in your code?

Comment: his issue seems to be to get the cardSet object at all :)

Comment: Just updated the code in my answer - I'm typing this without being able to test in Xcode, but something along those lines should work for you...

Comment: @james, is there a way to push the lesson name into the retrieved objects? I am asking because I want to pin the whole objects later on with `PFObject.pinAllInBackground(objects, block: nil)`

Answer (score 0):

you get passed an array of objects so you have to get the CardSet from the array:

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
    if (error == nil) {
        for object in objects { //note: if objects is always of size 1, just use objects[0]
            var cardset = object as CardSet //get the entry
            var lesson = cardset.lesson
        }
    }else{
        println(error.userInfo)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

first you must use includekey then save data as PFObject in findobjectwithdatablock  -> if data is PFUser save as PFUser else save as PFObject

Example :

```
var veriable  = (PFUser)() 
YourQueryFindObjectBlock {  
self.veriable = result["pointerCol"] as PFUser // if pointer has user data 
}
```